# std classes(initializer_list) hardcoded inside the compiler

Tags: c++, gcc, compiler-construction, g++

The issue: `initializer_list` can not be nested inside namespaces other than std because `{1, 2, 3}` evaluates to and only to `std::initializer_list`.

This is why I conclude that `std::initializer_list` is somehow hard-coded inside the compiler.

I also did the following test: if I change the line "`typedef size_t        size_type;`" to "`typedef long long size_type;`" from /usr/include/c++/5/initializer_list , programs that use initializer_list does not compile anymore. So, it seems like the compiler checks the integrity of the initializer_list structure. The errors message does not seems to be relevant.

Are there other such classes? If yes, where can I read more about these kind of anomalies?

Observations: I made the above tests using implementations from gcc and libcxx, with the g++-5.4 compiler (c++14)

Comment: An initializer list like `{ 1, 2, 3 }` is *supposed* to be converted to a `std::initializer_list` by the compiler. It's part of the C++ standard specification. The compiler also does a lot more implicitly, similar to that. Perhaps you can elaborate on your *actual* problem you have? *Why* are you asking about this?

Comment: @Some programmer dude Ok, and do you know of other classes that are considered by the compiler, like, for example, typeinfo?

Comment: Indeed `std::initializer_list` can be considered some sort of voodoo class as it does not obey regular rules in several ways. Let's just hope the common sense will prevail and it will get removed from the standard. Or at least we won't get any new magical compiler-emitted classes.

Comment: I fail to see what your first sentence is supposed to mean. The following works perfectly: `#include <initializer_list> namespace test { struct initializer_list {}; auto x = { 1, 2, 3 }; }`

Comment: @ Christian Hackl Try test::initializer_list x instead of auto x. The idea is that {1, 2, 3} returns std::initializer_list. But anyway, my question is if there are other classes like this and where I can read about this issue

Comment: What _is_ the issue? You're not supposed to edit standard library headers in the first place (you might break internal consistency in the library, or the compiler might make assumptions about what's in there), and you're not generally supposed to inject new stuff into `namespace std` either. Do you just want a list of every type with magic syntax or something?

Comment: @Useless I'm trying to rewrite some classes inside std and I need to figure what to ask from the compiler team. In order to be able to do this, I need to read about these special behaviours.

Comment: So you're writing your own standard library? Or trying to customise some parts, and customise a compiler to use your versions?

Comment: @Useless, Customising parts of it, there is another team that customize the compiler. The client needs the library in two namespaces: std and another one, but we are able to deliver initializer_list only in std

Comment: So your problem (roughly as per [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list), if you don't have a copy of the standard) is that the initializer list is implicitly constructed as a wrapper for an array, and the array syntax and implicit conversions are built into the compiler. So, ask the compiler team to replace their `std::initializer_list` implicit conversion with `custom::initializer_list` or whatever. It must be in there somewhere.